# Annotation Processing openjpa tomee in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, openjpa, apache-tomee, metamodel

I'm trying to use metamodel inside an eclipse project with tomee 1.7.1 server environment, and I don't use maven.

In order to generate metamodel class in eclipse :

In my project's properties -> Java Compiler -> Annotation Processing. i'm using processor option :
openjpa.metamodel:true

In my project's properties -> Java Compiler -> Annotation Processing -> Factory Path. I notified path :
tomee dir/lib/openjpa-2.4.0-nonfinal-1598334.jar

Unfortunately It does't work at all and I got this error message :

> Internal compiler error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceMetaDataDefaults at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceMetaDataFactory.(PersistenceMetaDataFactory.java:81)

I don't really know why, someone can help me please ?

Thank a lot

Eclipse error log :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceMetaDataDefaults
>       at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceMetaDataFactory.(PersistenceMetaDataFactory.java:81)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.AnnotationProcessor6.setNamingPolicy(AnnotationProcessor6.java:343)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.AnnotationProcessor6.init(AnnotationProcessor6.java:199)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.apt.pluggable.core.dispatch.IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.discoverNextProcessor(IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.java:93)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundDispatcher.round(RoundDispatcher.java:116)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.BaseAnnotationProcessorManager.processAnnotations(BaseAnnotationProcessorManager.java:159)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.apt.pluggable.core.dispatch.IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.processAnnotations(IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.java:134)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.processAnnotations(Compiler.java:818)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:434)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:367)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.compile(BatchImageBuilder.java:179)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:304)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.build(BatchImageBuilder.java:61)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildAll(JavaBuilder.java:256)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:175)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:358)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:381)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

Comment: You should post the full stacktrace. That might help someone understand what is going on.

Comment: I edited my first post. Can it help more ?